# Free HTML Image Map Editor for Windows?

Tags: html, imagemap

Does anybody here know of any free tools for creating HTML image maps? Googling seems to only get me tools that are for pay.

Comment: Questions like this can now be asked at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[X-Map](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/XMap/) is a nice, Free HTML Map Editor.  It was, however, last released in 2004, so it might not be very up-to-date.

Comment: +1 then again, nothing much changed wiht the image map over the years

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using a web-based generator try http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/

Found it googling for "html image map generator" and have used it several times recently to good success.

Answer (score 2):

Open source and a more recent project (last modified in June 2009) - ImgMap is an Adobe AIR based project. Works pretty well.

http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/

Answer (score 1):

Another free tool for generating HTML Imagemap Areas online pretty well:
http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de